# Force microphone on TRRS connector without a mic connected

Tags: resistors, audio, connector, microphone, android

I have a TRRS connector for my Android phone. I want to be able to enable/disable the mic on the cable using a button.

So for this I have connected a 1.2 kOhm resistor to a button and when its 'on' it will create a bridge over the Mic and ground connector, successfully muting the mic. If I leave it 'off', the microphone inputs data normally.

The problem is, the only way the Android phone uses the external MIC input  when connecting the cable for the first time is when the button is 'off'. If I connect it when the button is 'on' it will not switch to the external 'muted' mic.

Is there a way to force this behavior, connecting a 'muted' microphone over the TRRS connector?

Comment: A resistive load on the mic line means something specific to phones. Have you tried a capacitive load instead?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Are you suggesting it is a digital mic as per "microphone inputs data normally"?

Comment: @Andyaka Its just a normal analog mic, sorry about the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your mute switch to substitute a fixed resistor in place of the microphone capsule.  Select the resistor to give an equivalent static DC voltage on the connector so that the phone will recognize the "mic".